# Stored Procedure not working from QueriesTableAdapter

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, tableadapter

If I run the stored procedure in the DataSet Designer, it returns a value just fine. But when I call the stored procedure in my code, it returns nothing.

```
Private Function TotalAssignedHoursPerTopic(intNewTopic As Long) As Long

    Dim lngHours As Long

    lngHours = CLng(QueriesTableAdapter.TotalAssignedHoursPerTopic(intNewTopic))

    Return lngHours

End Function
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint, what are you seeing?

Comment: I actually ended up just creating a query on an existing tableadapter instead of a separate tableadapter and everything seems good now.